# How to debug: "HEADER ALREADY SENT" and GD2?

Tags: debugging, magento, gd2

I have an annoying HEADER ALREADY SENT error.

It is not easy to debug it, what I could do was to improve the logging to isolate the source of the issue ([has described here](http://codegento.com/2011/03/debugging-headers-already-sent-error/)):

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php, line 133
```

Here line 133 of `Gd2.php`:

```
call_user_func($this->_getCallback('output'), $this->_imageHandler);
```

And it is part of the method display:

```
public function display()
    {
        header("Content-type: ".$this->getMimeType());
        call_user_func($this->_getCallback('output'), $this->_imageHandler);
    }
```

How to go on ?

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to get this fixed. If so, how?

Comment: to be honest I don't remember ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Disable compilation and refresh cache

Comment: compilation is not enabled cache is cleaned regulary ... what cache you mean ?

Comment: I meant magento cache here...


But after you comments I think you must have done this



If not GOTO ADMIN >> SYSTEM >> CACHE MANAGEMENT
Refresh all cache



System > Tools > Compilation


Have you disabled from here

Comment: Try doing it without admin access like
http://kb.magenting.com/content/24/81/en/disable-magento-compiler.html